# Codeigniter textarea (angular.js ck editor ) Post not posting large data in controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter3.0 I have some issue in ck editor post data. when i try to post large text data and try to get in controller like `$this->input->post('textHeader');` it is not working. while I try to get like `$_POST['textHeader']`; it is working. any limit of codeigniter large data post?

Comment: How long is your text.i inserted 10 paragraphs of lorem lipsum using **$this->input->post('large');**.and it working fine.

Comment: Now i inserted 50 paragraphs of lorem lipsum using **Input Class** and it working fine but the text should be plain text.

Comment: My text is large full page content. more then 50 paragraph.

Comment: Ok now tested with 500 paragraphs working fine.Generated lipsum from [here](http://www.lipsum.com)

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think there is any limit of `codeigniter 3.0` for large data post.

Here is my form.

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/post_large'); ?>

<textarea name="large"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Post!" />

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My controller named **welcome** and **post_large** method.

```
public function post_large()
{
    echo $this->input->post('large');
}
```

This is working fine.